# AlamoFire5 Empty responseDecodable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

So I never used AlamoFire before and i'm also kind of a newbie when it comes to coding in xCode/SwiftUI. However when I try to fetch some Json data from my server with **responseDecodable** nothing is displayed. It looks like this just doesn't apply to my URL but every URL I try. I also tried https.

```
    AF.request("http://localhost:8000/api/events", headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: Welcome.self) { (response) in

    guard let event = response.value else { return }
    debugPrint(event.data[0].eventDetail)
```

When I use the function **responseJSON** it works perfectly and it returns a valid JSON string.

Please see my model below.

```
struct Welcome: Decodable, Hashable {
let success: Bool
let data: [Data]
let message: String }

let id, createdByOrganisationID, eventAssignedToUserid, eventType: Int
let eventHeaderImage, eventTitle, eventDetail, eventSubtitle: String
let eventCost: Int
let eventCountryID: Int
let eventAddressType: Int
let startDate, endDate: String

var description: String {
    return "\(eventTitle), id: \(id)"
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case createdByOrganisationID = "created_by_organisation_id"
    case eventAssignedToUserid = "event_assigned_to_userid"
    case eventType = "event_type"
    case eventHeaderImage = "event_header_image"
    case eventTitle = "event_title"
    case eventDetail = "event_detail"
    case eventSubtitle = "event_subtitle"
    case eventCost = "event_cost"
    case eventCountryID = "event_country_id"
    case eventAddressType = "event_address_type"
    case startDate = "start_date"
    case endDate = "end_date"
}}
```

And the Json data that the server returns:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "created_by_organisation_id": 1,
        "event_assigned_to_userid": 1,
        "event_type": 1,
        "event_header_image": "/image/",
        "event_title": "EVENT_TITLE",
        "event_detail": "TEXT",
        "event_subtitle": "EVENT_SUB",
        "event_cost": 500,
        "event_country_id": 1,
        "event_address_type": 0,
        "start_date": "2020-12-02",
        "end_date": "2020-12-03"
    }
],
"message": "Events retrieved successfully."
```

}

I just don't see what i'm doing wrong here since I followed a lot of tutorials that do the exact same thing with AlamoFire5 & Swift5.

Ps. I also get the right results in Postman.

*EDIT 26-04-2020*

Now that I know I get the right results since

`debugPrint(model.data[0].eventAssignedToUserid)`

gives the right value which means that the downloaded JSON does get stored in the model, awesome! Now I need to access this data from a view and I simply don't know how to. I tried adding `var event: [Data]` to the top of the view file and to access it I used:

`ForEach(event, id: \.self) { item in
    EventCardView(event: item)
}`

and within the EventCardView I use the following code:

```
var event: Data //Top of view outside the Var body: some View {}
Text(event.eventTitle) //just a quick example of how I display a title
```

But somehow this is always empty when I try to display anything.

Note: since I use a tabView I use a file called AppView which is the starting point for the app.

```
//AppView.swift
var event: [Data] //Again outside of the body.

ContentView(event: event) //First item in tabView
```

To call this function I use the 'application' function within AppDelegate to execute the function 'fetchEvent' because I need it on start up and I'd like to use it on other views too.

```
EventController().fetchEvent() { [weak self] (result) in
    guard let this = self else { return }
    this.handleResult(result)
}

private func handleResult(_ result: Result<Welcome, Error>) {
    switch result {
    case .success(let model):
        debugPrint(model.data[0].eventAssignedToUserid) //this return the right value
    case .failure(let error):
        debugPrint(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: `et data: [Data]`? Did you mean that Data is a custom Codable struct from your code which is missing (and which have the "id" property for instance)?

Comment: All I have been doing is following tutorials and I am also fairly new to this so I don't really get what you mean but it worked before when I had everything in this: `struct Event: Decodable, Hashable {
  var id: Int
  var event_header_image: String
  var event_title: String
  var event_subtitle: String
  var event_detail: String
  var event_cost: String
  var event_start_date: String
  var event_end_date: String
  let all: [Event]
    
    var description: String {
        return "\(event_title), id: \(id)"
    }
}`

Comment: And then I put this in a different file like this:

`let EventData: [Data] = [
 /* Data(
    id: 0,
    createdByOrganisationID: 1,
    eventAssignedToUserid: 1,
    eventType: 1,
    eventHeaderImage: "party",
    eventTitle: "Festival",
    eventDetail: ": 9 PM, Saturday",
    eventSubtitle: "Jazz / Rap / Classic / Alternative",
    eventCost:  250,
    eventCountryID: 0,
    eventAddressType: 0,
    startDate: "20-12-2012",
    endDate: "21-12-2012"
  )*/
]`

Comment: This worked perfectly so the only thing that I did was take that out and try to replace it with my own Json data

Comment: If you print the error the `responseDecodable` might be producing, it should tell you what's wrong with your `Decodable` implementation.

Comment: `guard case let .failure(error) = response.result else { return }
        debugPrint(error)`

This return nothing.

Comment: Well, you'll either have a `value` or an `error` off the `response`. You could just `debugPrint(response)` to see all of the content.

Comment: This is what it returns:

`success(testProj.Welcome(success: true, data: [testProj.Data(id: 1, createdByOrganisationID: 1, eventAssignedToUserid: 1, eventType: 1, eventHeaderImage: "/image/", eventTitle: "EVENT_TITLE", eventDetail: "GREAT_CHUNK_O_TEXT", eventSubtitle: "EVENT_SUB", eventCost: 500, eventCountryID: 1, eventAddressType: 0, startDate: "20-12-2012", endDate: "21-12-2012")], message: "Events retrieved successfully."))`

Comment: response.value?.data[0].eventCost

This seems to return the correct data! But how do I assign this to my model?

Comment: It has already been parsed as your model (you may want to rename your `Data` type to something more specific that doesn't collide with the existing type), you just need to call a completion handler to pass the value back to the call site.

Comment: Okay! I used `var event: Data` and then to display it `event.eventCost` but that doesn't show anything, i'll rename my `Data` type to something else when this is done just to not get confused.

Comment: I have been searching how to do this for over 3 days now and either nothing works because it's outdated or I just can't find the proper information.. could you help me with the completion handler process?

Comment: Since you've solved your parsing issue (or in addition to it), could you update your question with more detail about what you're trying to do and what isn't working? There's not really enough context for a good answer right now.

Comment: I updated my question! I hope this is enough context

Comment: This seems more like a SwiftUI question. I suggest you create a new question about that part of the issue, as your networking seems to be working.